# Check if ListBoxFor selectedValues is null before display in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.listboxfor

I have a number of ListBoxFor elements on a form in edit mode. If there was data recorded in the field then the previously selected items are displaying correctly when the form opens. If the field is empty though an error is thrown as the items parameter cannot be null. Is there a way to check in the view and if there is data to use the ListBoxFor with the four parameters but if there isn't to only use three parameters, leaving out the selected items?

This is how I'm declaring the ListBoxFor:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.IfQualityPoor, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.IfPoor, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.IfQualityPoorSelected), new { @class = "chosen", multiple = "multiple" })
```

I'm using the ViewBag to pass the ICollection which holds the selected items as the controller then joins or splits the strings for binding to the model field. The MultiSelectLists always prove problematic for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but you're making it way harder on yourself than it needs to be using `ListBoxFor`. All you need for either `DropDownListFor` or `ListBoxFor` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Razor will take care of selecting any appropriate values based on the `ModelState`.

So, assuming `ViewBag.IfPoor` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, all you need in your view is:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.IfQualityPoor, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.IfPoor, new { @class = "chosen" })
```

The correct options will be marked as `selected` based on the value of `IfQualityPoor` on your model, as they should be. Also, it's unnecessary to pass `multiple = "multiple"` in in your `htmlAttributes` param, as you get that just by using `ListBoxFor` rather than `DropDownListFor`.

It's even better if you use a view model and then add your options as a property. Then, you don't have to worry about casting in the view, which is always a good way to introduce runtime exceptions. For example:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IfQualityPoorOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you set this in your action, before returning the view (instead of setting `ViewBag`). Finally, in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.IfQualityPoor, Model.IfQualityPoorOptions, new { @class = "chosen" })
```

Much simpler, and you'll never have any issues doing it that way.

**UPDATE (based on comment)**

The best way to handle flattening a list into a string for database storage is to use a special property for that, and then custom getter and setter to map to/from. For example:

```
public string IfQualityPoor
{
    get { return IfQualityPoorList != null ? String.Join(",", IfQualityPoorList) : null; }
    set { IfQualityPoorList = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? value.Split(',').ToList() : null; }
}

[NotMapped]
public List<string> IfQualityPoorList { get; set; }
```

Then, you post to/interact with `IfQualityPoorList`, and the correct string will be set in the database automatically when you save.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I was doing it that way because I had to take the collection of selected values and join them into one comma-separated string and pass that back to the database as the value for IfQualityPoor. I'll try it your way now.

Comment: Tried your first option and it gives me an "The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when multiple selection is allowed." error.

Comment: That means that `IfQualityPoor` is not an enumerable. If you're doing a multiselect, then the property you're posting to must be a list-type, since it must accept multiple posted values. Again, if you need to actually persist something like a string, you still need to post to a list, but you can use the code I added in my update above to have the list automatically mapped to/from a string for persistence.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've no idea how much simpler that makes it, especially since I've so many multi select lists across multple forms